# Lucee with PostgreSQL - there are more question marks in the SQL than params defined

Tags: postgresql, coldfusion, lucee

I'm experiencing an issue while using PostgreSQL with Lucee on the backend. One of the tables has column with jsonb datatype. I'm using ? operator to check existence of the value. While this works when I run it in DBeaver, I'm experiencing an issue while processing the file with lucee. Please see the code below.

```
public query function getItems( uid ) {
     var sqlText = "
        SELECT ar.role_group, ar.role_indv 
        FROM app.app_roles ar, app.app_user au
        WHERE au.user_roles ? ar.role_id::text AND ar.role_is_active = 'Y' AND au.user_id = :uid
     ";
     return queryExecute( sqlText, {uid: { value: arguments.uid, cfsqltype: "integer" }}, {datasource : "my_dev"});
        }
writeDump(getItems(24));
```

SQL code is working and seems correct. The issue is on this line: `WHERE au.user_roles ? ar.role_id::text`

I couldn't figure out why Lucee is having issues with this code. Do any of you know a workaround for this issue? Please see error below.

```
Message: string there are more question marks in the SQL than params defined
```

Thank you.

Comment: queryExecute uses the question mark (?) as a placeholder for un-named parameters, maybe try escaping it as ??, I've not tried it but it might work ‍♂️

Comment: It's a known issue with Lucee: https://dev.lucee.org/t/postgres-error-using-question-mark-operator-in-cfquery/10061

Comment: @CfSimplicity is there any solution for this issue? I found the same post but there is no solution for this issue.

Comment: The OP in that post did find a workaround using some kind of EXISTS() function, but I'm not familiar with Postgres.

Comment: Did you try using `<cfquery>`?

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes - that works. However, my entire code is inside <cfscript>. I wouldn't like to use script tag just because of this problem...